# How to unload images from memory in an Android app

Tags: android, android-resources, android-memory

In an Android application, (answers to some other questions suggest that) image resources are loaded into memory when they are first used, e.g. when I call `ImageView.setImageResource(myResId)`.

How can I force an image resource to be unloaded from memory, to keep my memory footprint under control?

I have an app, a single activity with a viewpager on it: Many images in resources, one image for each view page. Image gets loaded when page is created, I want to unload it when user flips to another page. If the user comes back, image can be loaded again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to specifically unload images from memory. The best methods are calling recycle() after you're done with the object, and holding a weakreference to the object. To do that, you could do something like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewRef = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
```

whenever you want to access the image, you can use:

```
imageViewRef.get()
```

This way, when the app needs more memory, it can remove the image from memory as it doesn't have a hard reference to it.